# Getting bounding Box values from Googles ML Kit depending on the screen height

Tags: android, google-mlkit

I am using the [text recognition from Google's ML KIT (Version 19)](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2/andro). Everything works fine, but there is one thing I do not get. In my custom TextRecognizer I read the lines:

```
private void readLines(Text text){
  if (text != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.getTextBlocks().size(); ++i) {
      List<Line> lines = text.getTextBlocks().get(i).getLines();
      for (int j = 0; j < lines.size(); ++j) {
        Line line = lines.get(j);
        if(checkArea(line.getBoundingBox().centerY(), Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels) {
          doSomething(line.getText());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I only want to read the lines which are in center of the screen - therefore I split the screen into three parts and I read what is inside the middle part. You can see that in `checkArea`.

```
private boolean checkArea(float center, int screenHeight){
  return center > (screenHeight / 3) && center < ((screenHeight / 3) * 2);
}
```

The problem: It looks like the value of `line.getBoundingBox().centerY()` is not in the same unit as the screen height (`Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels`).

I think I have to do some rescaling or whatever. I have tried a calculation with the density of the device but nothing really fits.

Does someone know a valid calculation between these to values?

Comment: Need to convert the imageProxy coordinates to preview coordinates. Check out that page: https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/transform-output.

Comment: @SudoKoach thanks for your suggestion. I solved the problem in an other way - I take the image height as basic parameter - so the values (boundingBox.centerY) and height are in the same "unit". You know what I mean?